# slice array from N to last element

Tags: javascript

How to make this transformation?

```
["a","b","c","d","e"] // => ["c", "d", "e"]
```

I was thinking that `slice` can do this, but..

```
["a","b","c","d","e"].slice(2,-1) // [ 'c', 'd' ]
["a","b","c","d","e"].slice(2,0)  // []
```

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Don't use the second argument:

```
Array.slice(2);
```

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

> If end is omitted, slice extracts to the end of the sequence.

Comment: ok... but what if I can not predict if the end of the slice will be defined or not. In python we have str[start:None] to slice to the end. How can I equivalently do it on javascript ?

Comment: @yota If you know the length of the array you can pass that as second argument: `arr.slice(2, arr.length)`. If the second argument exceeds the array length, it’ll still return `begin` until the end of the sequence. If that’s not working for you, you will need an if-statement.

Answer (score 10):

An important consideration relating to the answer by @insomniac is that `splice` and `slice` are two **completely different functions**, with the main difference being:

- `splice` manipulates the original array.
- `slice` returns a sub-set of the original array, with the original array remaining untouched.

See: http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2014/02/javascript-array-slice-vs-splice.html for more information.

Answer (score 5):

Just give the starting index as you want rest of the data from the array..

```
["a","b","c","d","e"].splice(2) => ["c", "d", "e"]
```

Comment: the question was related to slice, not splice

Comment: Eh, it does _technically_ work, but if you care about the original array not being changed, don't do this as it will mutate. The starting array is now just `["a", "b"]`.

Answer (score 5):

```
["a","b","c","d","e"].slice(-3) => ["c","d","e"]
```

Comment: While this does achieve the desired result, you have to do some unnecessary arithmetic on N to get the negative number.

Answer (score 1):

Slice ends at the specified end argument but does not include it.  If you want to include it you have to specify the last index as the length of the array (5 in this case) as opposed to the end index (-1) etc.

```
["a","b","c","d","e"].slice(2,5) 
// = ['c','d','e']
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add a "-" before n
If the index is negative, the end indicates an offset from the end.

```
function getTail(arr, n) {
return arr.slice(-n);
}
```

Comment: This returns the last `n` entries, but not from entry `n` to the end.

Answer (score -3):

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
arr.splice(0,2);
console.log(arr);
```

Please use above code.
May be this you need.

Comment: the question was related to slice, not splice

Comment: Technically works, but mutates the array.