# Code to get last 2 items from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to get last 2 items from an array

```
result.forEach(function (re) {

console.log(re.files)
// prints ["utilities.rb", "print_utilities.rb", "lities.rb", "agination.rb"]
});
```

i only want to last two elements in the array in the order

```
 [ "agination.rb", "print_utilities.rb"]
```

How it is possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [slice array from N to last element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395050/slice-array-from-n-to-last-element)

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Array.prototype.slice` method for this with a negative index.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> As a negative index, begin indicates an offset from the end of the
>   sequence. slice(-2) extracts the last two elements in the sequence.

slice returns a new array, so you can store the result in a new variable.

So in your case, simply use:

```
var arrayWithLast2Items = re.files.slice(-2);
```

Comment: how to acccend that array

Answer (score 0):

jquery provides a `slice` method for this

e.g

```
$([1,2,3]).slice(-2)
```

https://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: why load jQuery for a normal function in vanilla javascript?

Answer (score -1):

Have a temp array with size 2, iterate the elements of original array and over write/copy elements to the temp array.
Once iteration is complete, the temp array will contain last 2 elements of original array.